# Timer1 doesnt generate an Output while Timer3 does (STM32L552)

Tags: c, timer, stm32

I am trying to use the output compare mode of TIMER1 to produce an accurate time course on the PE9 pin. For some reason I don't get an output signal on this pin. Instead, when I use TIMER3 with the same settings as TIMER1, I get an output signal on pin PC7.

What is the reason for this? What can I change to also get the output signal from TIMER1?

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2022 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
#include "main.h"

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void);
static void MX_ICACHE_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void);


/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{

  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_TIM1_Init();
  MX_ICACHE_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();

  
  LL_TIM_CC_EnableChannel(TIM1, LL_TIM_CHANNEL_CH1);
  LL_TIM_EnableCounter(TIM1);
  LL_TIM_GenerateEvent_UPDATE(TIM1);

  LL_TIM_CC_EnableChannel(TIM3, LL_TIM_CHANNEL_CH2);
  LL_TIM_EnableCounter(TIM3);
  LL_TIM_GenerateEvent_UPDATE(TIM3);
  

  while (1)
  {

  }

}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  LL_FLASH_SetLatency(LL_FLASH_LATENCY_5);
  while(LL_FLASH_GetLatency()!= LL_FLASH_LATENCY_5)
  {
  }

  LL_PWR_SetRegulVoltageScaling(LL_PWR_REGU_VOLTAGE_SCALE0);
  LL_RCC_HSI48_Enable();

   /* Wait till HSI48 is ready */
  while(LL_RCC_HSI48_IsReady() != 1)
  {
  }

  LL_RCC_LSI_Enable();

   /* Wait till LSI is ready */
  while(LL_RCC_LSI_IsReady() != 1)
  {
  }

  LL_RCC_MSI_Enable();

   /* Wait till MSI is ready */
  while(LL_RCC_MSI_IsReady() != 1)
  {
  }

  LL_RCC_MSI_EnableRangeSelection();
  LL_RCC_MSI_SetRange(LL_RCC_MSIRANGE_6);
  LL_RCC_MSI_SetCalibTrimming(0);
  LL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
  LL_RCC_PLL_ConfigDomain_SYS(LL_RCC_PLLSOURCE_MSI, LL_RCC_PLLM_DIV_1, 55, LL_RCC_PLLR_DIV_2);
  LL_RCC_PLL_ConfigDomain_48M(LL_RCC_PLLSOURCE_MSI, LL_RCC_PLLM_DIV_1, 55, LL_RCC_PLLQ_DIV_2);
  LL_RCC_PLL_EnableDomain_48M();
  LL_RCC_PLL_EnableDomain_SYS();
  LL_RCC_PLL_Enable();

   /* Wait till PLL is ready */
  while(LL_RCC_PLL_IsReady() != 1)
  {
  }

   /* Intermediate AHB prescaler 2 when target frequency clock is higher than 80 MHz */
   LL_RCC_SetAHBPrescaler(LL_RCC_SYSCLK_DIV_2);

  LL_RCC_SetSysClkSource(LL_RCC_SYS_CLKSOURCE_PLL);

   /* Wait till System clock is ready */
  while(LL_RCC_GetSysClkSource() != LL_RCC_SYS_CLKSOURCE_STATUS_PLL)
  {
  }

  /* Insure 1µs transition state at intermediate medium speed clock based on DWT*/
  CoreDebug->DEMCR |= CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk;

  DWT->CTRL |= DWT_CTRL_CYCCNTENA_Msk;
  DWT->CYCCNT = 0;
  while(DWT->CYCCNT < 100);

  LL_RCC_SetAHBPrescaler(LL_RCC_SYSCLK_DIV_1);
  LL_RCC_SetAPB1Prescaler(LL_RCC_APB1_DIV_1);
  LL_RCC_SetAPB2Prescaler(LL_RCC_APB2_DIV_1);
  LL_SetSystemCoreClock(110000000);

   /* Update the time base */
  if (HAL_InitTick (TICK_INT_PRIORITY) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief ICACHE Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_ICACHE_Init(void)
{
  /** Enable instruction cache in 1-way (direct mapped cache)
  */
  LL_ICACHE_SetMode(LL_ICACHE_1WAY);
  LL_ICACHE_Enable();
}

/**
  * @brief TIM1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{
  LL_TIM_InitTypeDef TIM_InitStruct = {0};
  LL_TIM_OC_InitTypeDef TIM_OC_InitStruct = {0};
  LL_TIM_BDTR_InitTypeDef TIM_BDTRInitStruct = {0};

  LL_GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* Peripheral clock enable */
  LL_APB2_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB2_GRP1_PERIPH_TIM1);

  TIM_InitStruct.Prescaler = 10999;
  TIM_InitStruct.CounterMode = LL_TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  TIM_InitStruct.Autoreload = 9999;
  TIM_InitStruct.ClockDivision = LL_TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  LL_TIM_Init(TIM1, &TIM_InitStruct);
  LL_TIM_DisableARRPreload(TIM1);
  TIM_OC_InitStruct.OCMode = LL_TIM_OCMODE_TOGGLE;
  TIM_OC_InitStruct.OCState = LL_TIM_OCSTATE_DISABLE;
  TIM_OC_InitStruct.OCNState = LL_TIM_OCSTATE_DISABLE;
  TIM_OC_InitStruct.CompareValue = 0;
  TIM_OC_InitStruct.OCPolarity = LL_TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  LL_TIM_OC_Init(TIM1, LL_TIM_CHANNEL_CH1, &TIM_OC_InitStruct);
  LL_TIM_OC_DisableFast(TIM1, LL_TIM_CHANNEL_CH1);
  LL_TIM_SetTriggerOutput(TIM1, LL_TIM_TRGO_CC1IF);
  LL_TIM_SetTriggerOutput2(TIM1, LL_TIM_TRGO2_CC1F);
  LL_TIM_DisableMasterSlaveMode(TIM1);

  LL_AHB2_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_AHB2_GRP1_PERIPH_GPIOE);
  /**TIM1 GPIO Configuration
  PE9   ------> TIM1_CH1
  */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LL_GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = LL_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.OutputType = LL_GPIO_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = LL_GPIO_PULL_NO;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = LL_GPIO_AF_1;
  LL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/**
  * @brief TIM3 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{
  LL_TIM_InitTypeDef TIM_InitStruct = {0};
  LL_TIM_OC_InitTypeDef TIM_OC_InitStruct = {0};

  LL_GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* Peripheral clock enable */
  LL_APB1_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB1_GRP1_PERIPH_TIM3);

  TIM_InitStruct.Prescaler = 10999;
  TIM_InitStruct.CounterMode = LL_TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  TIM_InitStruct.Autoreload = 9999;
  TIM_InitStruct.ClockDivision = LL_TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  LL_TIM_Init(TIM3, &TIM_InitStruct);
  LL_TIM_DisableARRPreload(TIM3);
  TIM_OC_InitStruct.OCMode = LL_TIM_OCMODE_TOGGLE;
  TIM_OC_InitStruct.OCState = LL_TIM_OCSTATE_DISABLE;
  TIM_OC_InitStruct.OCNState = LL_TIM_OCSTATE_DISABLE;
  TIM_OC_InitStruct.CompareValue = 0;
  TIM_OC_InitStruct.OCPolarity = LL_TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  LL_TIM_OC_Init(TIM3, LL_TIM_CHANNEL_CH2, &TIM_OC_InitStruct);
  LL_TIM_OC_DisableFast(TIM3, LL_TIM_CHANNEL_CH2);
  LL_TIM_SetTriggerOutput(TIM3, LL_TIM_TRGO_CC1IF);
  LL_TIM_DisableMasterSlaveMode(TIM3);

  LL_AHB2_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_AHB2_GRP1_PERIPH_GPIOC);
  /**TIM3 GPIO Configuration
  PC7   ------> TIM3_CH2
  */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LL_GPIO_PIN_7;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = LL_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.OutputType = LL_GPIO_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = LL_GPIO_PULL_NO;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = LL_GPIO_AF_2;
  LL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}


/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{

}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with HAL libraries but the first possible cause comes to my mind is **MOE** bit of **TIMx_BDTR** register. Only TIM1 & TIM8 have this bit (and register) and it needs to be set to get output from pins.

Please try this function, which basically just sets the **MOE** bit:

```
LL_TIM_EnableAllOutputs(TIM1);
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Now it's working.